# Listbox acting weird

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a weird issue in my Windows Phone 8 project. I have a very basic page with only just a ListBox control on it with some items in it.
When I start the project it only shows the first item but it doesn't open when I click it.
Here's my code:

```
    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="Diablo 3 Compagnion" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter battletag" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" Height="100">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Name="lb" Width="100" Height="30" SelectionMode="Single">
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Which part of the XAML you posted would you hope to perform an action that resembles *opening* an item?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by your question. I am expecting the same kind of functionality as with a normal HTML dropdownlist. So only 1 option will be shown and when you click it, it drops down and shows the available options. But not it show all the options all the time and I don't see any properties which can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a combobox not a listbox. You can use the following:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Height="30">
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 1</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 2</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 3</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 4</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 5</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem>Item 6</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Actually the ComboBox was the first control i used but it had the same problem.